# Disallow unchecking of all checkboxes in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive, checklist-model

I'm using AngularJS directive for list of checkboxes [checklist-model](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model) but I need to keep at least one check box checked at all times.
I've changed the [checklist-model.js](https://rawgit.com/ozba/97f98bbfee283622ccc9/raw/80d3371de0ea5bfedc3e4a39fde2e78fe6c01122/checklist-model.js) by adding an if:

```
watch if(current.length > 1)
```

before removing a check:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue === oldValue) { 
    return;
  } 
  var current = getter(scope.$parent);
  if (angular.isFunction(setter)) {
    if (newValue === true) {
      setter(scope.$parent, add(current, value, comparator));
    } else {
        if(current.length > 1)
        {
            setter(scope.$parent, remove(current, value, comparator));
        }
    }
  }

  if (checklistChange) {
    checklistChange(scope);
  }
});
```

The problem is that the UI has already changed to unchecked while the model did not change.

Anyone has an elegant suggestion (preferably without JQuery) on how to change the checkbox back to "checked" state, or even better to catch it before it changed to checked?

JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebv3p/642/), try to uncheck all and see that when the check boxes are all unchecked (what I'm trying to prevent) the model stays not empty (which is good but not enough)

Comment: I understand your problem, but I think your looking for the wrong solution.  If the user wan't to disable a checkbox, just let him do it. Otherwise he has to select another checkbox and THEN he can uncheck the old one?? That behavior you describe is a terrible user experience. Keep it simple and use form validation to show a warning if he unchecks all checkboxes and disable the submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine suggested to disable the checkbox once it's the only one selected, that way you both prevent the changing of the module (therefore the directive does not even need to change) and the UX is better as the user understands he can't uncheck it:

```
     <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id" ng-disabled="shouldDisable(role.id)"> {{role.text}}

 $scope.shouldDisable = function(roleId) {
        var isDisabled = false;
        if($scope.user.roles.length === 1) {
            isDisabled = $scope.user.roles.indexOf(roleId) !== -1;
        }
        return isDisabled;
    }
```

See answer in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebv3p/658/) JSfiddle

Answer (score 2):

This probably comes from asynchronous nature of angular and the library you are using. What I could find so far is some dirty workaround like this ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ebv3p/650/)): create an event where you track the clicks on input and do the following:

```
  $scope.onclick = function(evt) {
    if ($scope.user.roles.length === 1 && prevLength === 1) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }

    prevLength = $scope.user.roles.length;
  };
```

then add it it to your element

```
 ng-click="onclick($event)"
```

I don't say it's perfect but it works

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, the component does not support this, but there's a discussion to implement minlength/maxlength https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model/issues/15 and then this would be simply implemented by using `checklist-minlength=1`.

I also edited your proposal to implement `checklistBeforeChange`. I will try to handle this too in the next batch. Implemented in v0.8.0.

Comment: Implemented in v0.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer version to @ozba answer using the array.some function:

```
public atLeastOneRowEnabled(row): boolean {
        //at least one row is visible except the current line
        return !this.rows.some(rowIterator => rowIterator.logical_name !== row.logical_name && rowIterator.isVisible);
    }
```